# Force title labels to be displayed

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

I have a Highcharts configuration that is using the "`Step`" property under `label` to force displaying title. But I still see that the titles are ignored by Highcharts randomly. Is there a consistent way to enforce Highcharts to always display title text regardless of the length of the title text?

I tried to use a formatter callback function to restrict the length or format the label text but somehow this looks more of a hack than a proper solution.

Comment: Do you have an example (JSFiddle or similar) of your problem?

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't get a jsfiddle as the chart is rendered as part of a big webpage that I couldn't extract configurations.